# Are there any good tools for integrating GWT with ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gwt

Are there any good tools available for using GWT (the Google Web Toolkit) with an ASP.Net server application?  The programming model and tools for GWT are quite nice, however, it would be nice if the backend could remain in C#/ASP.Net.

Is there currently a good solution available for this?

Answer (score 24):

I am working on a GWT project where ASP.NET is my only option on the server.  I have found that, while it requires a little extra work, [JavaScript Overlay](http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2008/08/getting-to-really-know-gwt-part-2.html) types can make it easy.  It doesn't matter what technology your server is using, so long as it can respond with JSON serialized data.  For instance, if you have a Contact class in C#:

```
public class Contact 
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Design your server so that it returns this serialized as JSON.  I use ASP.NET MVC for this because it requires so little work.  Here's a very simple example where we'll assume that Contact has a static method that, given an id, will return a Contact instance:

```
public class ContactController : Controller 
{
  public ActionResult GetContact (int id) 
  {
    return Json(Contact.GetById(id), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
}
```

Now, in your GWT application, create a JavaScript overlay type for your Contact:

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptObject;

public class Contact extends JavaScriptObject {
  protected Contact() { }

  public final native int getContactId() /*-{ return this.Id; }-*/;
  public final native String getLastName() /*-{ return this.LastName; }-*/;
  public final native String getFirstName() /*-{ return this.FirstName; }-*/;
  public final native String getEmail() /*-{ return this.Email; }-*/;

  public static final native Contact createFromJson(String json) /*-{
    return eval('(' + json + ')');
  }-*/;
}
```

Next, in your GWT project, use an HTTP request to communicate with the server:

```
public class ContactLoader {
  private int id; 

  public ContactLoader(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public void beginLoad() {
    String url = "/YourService/GetContact/?id=" + id;
    RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, url);
    try {
      @SuppressWarnings("unused")
      builder.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onResponseReceived(Request req, Response resp) {
          Contact contact = Contact.createFromJson(req.getText());
          // do something with your contact.  In my project, I
          // fire an event here for which the contact is the payload
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
          // handle your error
        }
    catch (Exception exception) {
      // handle your error
    }
  }
}
```

It is also possible to use generic types with overlay types.  For example, I never return a bare object, I always use a generic container for transport so that I can easily handle error reporting on the client side.

C#:

```
public class ServerResponse<T> 
{
  public T Payload { get; set; }
  public bool Success { get; set; }
  public String Message { get; set; }
}
```

Java:

```
public class ServerResponse<T extends JavascriptObject> 
  extends JavaScriptObject {
  protected ServerResponse() { }

  public final native T getPayload() /*-{ return this.Payload; }-*/;
  public final native boolean getSuccess() /*-{ return this.Success; }-*/;
  public final native String getMessage() /*-{ return this.Message; }-*/;
}
```

This lets me return my Contact, an array of Contacts or whatever.  It also helps in reducing duplication in your data loading logic.

This is an overly simple example, but hopefully it is enough to clear a path for anyone needing help with a non-Java back-end. Another resource that I found helpful that discusses overlay types is "[JSON Parsing with JavaScript Overlay Types in GWT](http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/json_parsing_with_javascript_overlay)" by Matt Raible.

Comment: I think this is the answer which responds to the question.

Comment: Great answer, well done. It's a shame yours wasn't the one marked as 'Answer'.

Answer (score 7):

According to the [GWT FAQ](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/FAQ_Server.html#How_do_I_make_a_call_to_the_server_if_I_am_not_using_GWT_RPC?), you should be able to do this.

> The heart of AJAX is making data read/write calls to a server from the JavaScript application running in the browser. GWT is "RPC agnostic" and has no particular requirements about what protocol is used to issue RPC requests, or even what language the server code is written in. Although GWT provides a library of classes that makes the RPC communications with a J2EE server extremely easy, you are not required to use them. Instead you can build custom HTTP requests to retrieve, for example, JSON or XML-formatted data.

I'm not aware of any projects to simplify the object serialization/deserialization logic though, if that was your question.

The client-side GWT code gets compiled to javascript, therefore it doesn't matter what server you use to serve it.

Comment: Right, you would just have to re-implement the same API found in their example J2EE library as an ASP.NET application routing for remote-procedure handlers, perhaps using ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: thats only true if you want to use their bundled RPC mechanism. That mechanism can be replaced with a json backed RPC mechanism (i googled gwt json rpc and got a couple of results), or you can even use a REST backed RPC mechanism (try this http://code.google.com/p/gwt-rest/ , or google for more, there are a couple). I.e., the RPC mechanism is replacable, and there are libraries out there that already does it.

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking for the same thing - I've found something similar to what GWT does for ASP.Net called Script#. It is written by the same guy that was mainly responsible for ASP.NET AJAX - Nikhil Kothari.  The site is: http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp

It basically takes C# code and compiles it to Javascript - the same thing that GWT does (only it does it with Java)

I honestly think that GWT can work with ASP.NET and even ASP.NET MVC - I reckon that you'd need JSON or XML serving generic handlers (.ashx) in ASP.NET for GWT to work.  I havent tried it myself..

Forgive me if I've confused anyone..

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the Smart GWT library -  its data-binding layer can directly call SOAP web services (standard .asmx).

Answer (score 2):

Anybody reading this question: please ignore the Accepted answer.  It's completely mistaken.  The OP wants to use GWT with an ASP.Net backend, he doesn't want to produce GWT using ASP.Net.  Any backend language that can produce JSON/JSONP can quickly integrate with GWT via Javascript overlays.

Answer (score 1):

Try [SharpKit](http://sharpkit.net), it allows you to write in C#, and convert to JavaScript during compilation. It also available as a command line executable. It supports many popular web libraries like jQuery, it also supports full C# 4 language syntax and .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SmartGWT, it includes a RestDataSource which provides a pre-built JSON or XML protocol that you can implement in .NET.  This series of articles from our public wiki shows how to build an ASP.NET MVC backend for RestDataSource that implements all 4 CRUD operations, database transactions and support for SmartGWT AdvancedCriteria (using NHibernate):

http://wiki.smartclient.com/display/Main/Integrating+with+ASP.Net+MVC

In this particular case, SmartClient was used rather than SmartGWT, but all the backend code is identical (SmartGWT just provides GWT support for SmartClient; it's the same code under the hood).  The front-end code is trivial and easily translated to SmartGWT.

This code on the wiki is all free, and so is the editing of SmartGWT needed to build the front-end (it's open source under the LGPL).

Answer (score 0):

smcmahon's answer truly helped my company get this going, and now we are doing this regularly - developing the front end using GWT and the backend with .NET/MS technologies.

I've been a MS developer my whole life - latest silverlight frontend with .net backend.  it took about a month worth of work but finally we implemented a smooth process to develop single page GWT apps in Eclipse, using .NET backend/web services developed in visual studio 2010.  On the .NET side we receive/transfer all objects in JSON rather than XML (we use Newtonsoft JSON generator because .NET default JSON generation from WCF web services gave problems, especially with dates).  On the GWT side we use overlay types.

We wrote an app which generates code (from the .NET app) and automatically writes it to our GWT project - it generates all classes that we need and also writes functions for easy calls to the web services.  On top of this, we were able to get the .NET web services functioning while we run the app in GWT, which makes it WAY easy to debug.  then when we are done with project changes, we compile to javascript/html - copy that to visual studio, and deploy our project.  couldn't be simpler.

It took a lot of work to figure all this out with the help of this thread, but was TOTALLY worth it once we did since we are a straight microsoft shop with SQL server backend and IIS windows servers.  Silverlight was great, but now we are moving to the point where staff are getting pads and need to run apps on their phones as well.

We use UIBinder for the interface.  Love the GUI designer/xml declarative layout, and modularity.  Can still use any HTML/CSS we want by having the UiBinder HTML panels in the UI.  The uiBinder designer even recognizes CSS3 tags and renders them better than IE9 does.

GWT was a great solution, and Java was very easy to learn coming from a C# background.