# any example or tutorial for how to connect to MS SQL Server in a GWT project

Tags: java, sql-server, gwt

I'm having hard time to find out how to read and write from /into MS SQL server 2008 using GWT .
does any body know of any step by step guide or sample that can help me ?

thanks

Comment: gwt is not an issue, You can not connect to MSSQL db at gwt layer. Therefore  you can search google how to connect to a mssql database by using jdbc or an orm tools.

Comment: Which servlet container are you using?

Comment: I'm very new to GWT (I'm .Net developer) but have to develop a project in GWT so I can use any servlet container (something that work :D )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to uses Microsofts JDBC connector instead of MySQL connector

[connect with ms sql](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-examples/wiki/project_MS_SQLConn)

[Database Access in GWT – The Missing Tutorial](http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3aAOZLkHHXgbIJ%3awww.tenbergen.org/misc/DB-Access-in-GWT-The-Missing-Tutorial.pdf%20gwt%20tutorial%20using%20database&hl=en&gl=in&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESgycvZFgxk936WJYW7O9FIZYgti7d2VOgsnYUclg7m0qmtbviTnH5uyxVwwnpN8j1Wr04i6HZicykrQCUkjVfAdFf-EJh-lO1GdvXl4hhz_VI8l9uZlkDw1lkwOU_v4skmawHee&sig=AHIEtbQuc-y-p-4cA-CHOJrBJYSmQpBDlg)

Comment: I've tried this one , it's just two classes doesn't say anything about how to use it

Comment: have tried that one as well , no joy :( thanks for trying to help (+1)

Comment: you have to change just 4 line of jdbc connection and wanna use Microsoft jdbc connector jar in place of mysql connector jar.

Answer (score 3):

you indicate you're a .Net developer.

In your shoes, I'd follow this strategy:

- just use GWT for the client-side
- use .Net for the server-side
- connect client-side to server-side via REST, this will de-couple the two and provide a wider choice for future upgrade/enhancement
- develop a REST backend via your favourite .Net server side ASP engine (VB/C#) It's this backend that will connect to MS-SQL, plus it may contain some business processes. You could even do this with Classic ASP - as I've had to ;-)

So:  MS-SQL is your data layer, GWT is your UI layer, ASP is your business layer.

Here's a StackOverflow question covering it [Are there any good tools for integrating GWT with ASP.Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885232/are-there-any-good-tools-for-integrating-gwt-with-asp-net)   Ignore the first answer - it's complete horse-sh*t.  The second answer (GWT/ASP.Net) gives a good strategy.  Use Javascript Overlay types to read in the json returned from your backend and make it appear as GWT objects.

Comment: looks like a very good idea , I'm C# developer so I can create the layer in C# for connecting to database and returning data but can you tell/show me how I can use the developed .Net lib in the GWT code ?

Comment: Hi, you won't use it in the GWT code.  Your .Net code will be running from a MS Windows web-server such as IIS.  You'll have a page titled something like "prices.aspx". This page will take a parameter representing the item id of interest.  It will look up the data in the database, collate it as jsonp, and return that text. Your GWT may be running in IIS, or on another web server. It will know to call prices.aspx?itemId=1243. It will call that page, then parse the result (see JSONPRequestBuilder GWT examples).